# How to identify or extract the rows where two column values (Amount fields) are different in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, comparison, compare

Rather than manually going through millions of records, is there a way to find the records which has difference in two amount columns? Is there a query to do it for me?

For example, Table A contains ColA and ColB with amountss on this and the datatype is "Money" on both columns. There are few instances where values are different (It's decimal values, apparently, yeah? Yes, because its money field).

Can somebo0dy help me with a query to extract the rows with difference in money values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both are same datatype. You just need to check ColA <> ColB.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA  WHERE ColA <> ColB
```

Comment: might need to consider NULL value if either one of the column is nullable

Comment: ofcourse. Answer just let him the path to do how. Not the exact query.

Comment: @Veera: Simple to understand and short and sweet query, Veera Rajini pola vandhu help pannitenga superstar.....Bye

Answer (score 1):

To consider rows where ColA or ColB are null you can write as:

```
select ColA, ColB
from TableA
where Isnull(ColA,0) - Isnull(ColB ,0) != 0
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/YTMK78987)</kbd>

Comment: Deep, I do not understand your query.

Comment: Logic I have applied is differnce of two equal values is `0`. So select all rows where difference is not `0` and in case any column value in a row is Null consider it as 0 using `ISNULL` operator. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Deepshikha, I have given a + to both your answer as well as your explanation now :) Sorry you were a bit late, I got the ans for Veer immediately next second of posting my query. You have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can query rows having some conditions using where clause.

```
Select * from Table where Column1 operator Column2
```

So, here you can write:

```
Select * from TableA where ColA <> ColB
```